# WooCommerce product category with Arabic slug returns page not found

Tags: woocommerce, arabic, slug

I have an WooCommerce store which is in Arabic, whenever I create product category and write slug in Arabic it returns page not found. If I change the slug to English it work perfectly.
In both cases the product category name is in Arabic.

I tried adding the following code to config.php with no help:

```
if ( isset($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']) ) {
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL'];
}
```